# Should I mention being enrolled in distance course currently as a backup option in application form?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am currently enrolled in a distance masters's course in my country as a backup. I will be only applying to some really very competitive schools. If I don't make it through those schools I will apply next year or year after that and continue to do so till I make it in. I am very very passionate about these schools and the research going on in there.

Class for this distance course will begin by the end of this month and I will quit as soon as I get an admit in any school of my choice. Should I mention joining the course in my application forms?

Some of these schools want me to upload transcripts of any course I have attended after school. Considering the fact that the course has not yet begun there is no way I could get a transcript from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule of thumb is this: if you're actively involved in something *at the time of application*, then you should mention it. If you're *tentatively* enrolled (for example, you've been offered admission, but have not yet officially registered), then it doesn't actually count, and you need not mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar's a little strange, but as I understood your question: (1) you haven't taken any classes in said program, and (2) you don't plan to if you get into another program.  In this case, no, there's no need to and I can't see how it would help at all.  If you do plan to take at least 1 class even if you get into the program you're applying to (so you would have extra experience currently not documented before your desired program starts), then you can mention this in a cover letter or other appropriate place on the application.

Comment: I am not hoping to get an advantage by showing that I am currently enrolled in some course. I am worried that I might violate some rule by not declaring that I am enrolled in some course. I am a Indian student BTW. I am worried that I might run into some VISA issues or something.

Comment: Most of the application forms make it pretty clear that I need to mention all the colleges I have attended after high school. But my situation is kinda atypical so I dunno, whether what it says in the form applies to me or not. I tried mailing them but since this being admission season and all, I didn't get any response from them. So I was hoping that someone here could help me.

Comment: It sounds like the instructions say you need to submit transcripts for any post-secondary schools previously attended.  Being enrolled to take a course does not count as having attended, so they are not asking for something which does not exist.